# Facing this issue @driver.quit giving error in after (:context ) in rspec

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, rspec, automation

I am trying this

```
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

RSpec.describe 'New test' do

  before :each do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for (:firefox)
  end

  after :all do
    @driver.quit
  end

  it 'should signup and create a new user' do
    p 'testing'
  end
end
```

And this is the error I get

```
rspec test.rb                                                                                                                     [13:04:18]
"testing"
.
An error occurred in an `after(:context)` hook.
Failure/Error: @driver.quit

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `quit' for nil:NilClass
# ./test.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 4.61 seconds (files took 0.17828 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

I am sure it is a small thing that i am missing but could not find it any help would be appreciated.

Is this a FF or selenium version issue?

I am using FF 45 and selenium 2.53 and rspec 3.5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an RSpec issue.  before/after(:all) hooks only have access to instance variables defined in their scope or outer scope levels, but not to instance variables declared in the current spec being run.  after(:each) hooks do have access to the instance variables declared in the current spec.

```
before :all do
 @a = 2
end

context "blah" do
  before :all do
    @b = 3
  end

  it "blah blah" do
    @c = 4
    # @a,@b,@c all accessible here
  end

  after :each do
   #@a, @b, @c accessible here
  end

  after :all do
    # @a,@b  accessible here
  end
end

after :all do
   #can access @a
end
```